# How can I wrap this text so it doesn't overflow past the widget container?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a Wordpress widget and inside the widget I am displaying profile information. Some times the text for the 2nd row is too long and it overflows past the widget container.

[image]

What would be a good way to deal with this, and how could I implement it in css or html or whatever?

My css

```
#profileContainer { 
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    display:block;    
    padding: 5px;
}

#avatarContainer {
    width: 55px;
    float: left;
    padding: 5 5 5 5;
}

#dataContainer {
    float: left;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    word-wrap: break-word;    
}

#dataList {
    display: inline-block;    
}
```

My html for the output

```
?>
<div id="profileContainer">
<?php
$img = bp_core_fetch_avatar( 'html=false&item_id=' . $author->getId() );
$img_html = '<img src="' . $img . '"></img>';

?>
<div id="avatarContainer">
<?php        

if ($author->getUrl() != null) {    
    echo "<a href='" . $author->getUrl() . "'>" . $img_html . "</a>";
} else {
    echo $img_html;
}
?>
</div> <!--closing avatar container div -->

<div class="overflow-hidden">
<?php

if ($author->getName() != null) {
    echo "<b>" . $author->getName() . "</b>";
}

if ($author->getJobTitle() != null) {
    echo "<br/>" . $author->getJobTitle();
}

if ($author->getUserName() != null) {
    if ($author->getUrl() != null) {
        echo "<br/><a href='" . $author->getUrl() . "'>@" . $author->getUserName() . "</a>";
    } else {
        echo "<br/>@" . $author->getUserName();
    }
}

if ($author->getEmail() != null) {
    echo '<br/><a href="mailto:' . $author->getEmail() . '">' . $author->getEmail() . "</a>";
}

if ($author->getPhone() != null) {
    echo "<br/> " . $author->getPhone();
}

echo "<br/>";

?>
</div> <!--closing data container div -->
</div> <!--closing container div-->
<?php
```

Comment: Hey Albert, please supply the relevant code so that it is easier for us to take a look at the issue for you. 

It looks like a `width` issue though.

Comment: @BeatAlex I just updated my post with my css

Comment: @BeatAlex also just added the html

Comment: Can you give us dummy data instead of your php code? Thanks.

Comment: @BeatAlex I mean the data is just text from the Author class so like $author->getName() would just be like "String"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in css do this to wrap text in elipsis mode (three dots)

```
.overflow-hidden{
    max-width:400px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: do I need to add an overflow hidden attribute to my divs?

Comment: So I just tried adding that to my dataContainer div (which holds all the text) and it didn't do anything.

Comment: this is strange, give me  a moment to test this.